# Database performance: varchar index vs integer order column

Tags: sqlite, database-design

I'm using a SQLite database in my Android app. I have a non-variable table with, more or less, 500 rows. I want to query these rows ordered by a varchar column (alphabetical order).

What would be faster:

- Add an index on that column

or

- Sorting this data in-memory and then persist with an integer ordering column?

My first approach was add an index but then I have studied that indexes on varchar columns are not quite efficient.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an index with the ordering column *and* all other columns you're querying, you have a [covering index](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx) which allows to retrieve the rows in the correct order without sorting and without having to look up rows in the table.

That said, 500 rows is tiny.
I don't expect any noticeable difference.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do it this way.